# Как проверить подключились ли шрифты CSS

Tags: css, frontend, шрифты

Как проверить подключились ли шрифты CSS или нет?

Comment: В Dev tools справа, в calculated

Comment: библиотека от typekit/google https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Comment: и вот такая штука на jQuery - https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/jQuery-FontSpy.js

Answer (score 1):

Вот способ проверить загрузилась ли css, плюс ожидание окончания загрузки

```
var css = document.head.querySelector('link[href*="path.to.css"]');
var cssLoaded = css ? css.sheet.cssRules.length : false;
!cssLoaded && css.addEventListener('load', function () {
  cssLoaded = true;
});
```

однако со шрифтами все может быть сложнее, т.к. Возможно что css шрифта в свою очередь будет запрашивать ещё ресурсы с сервера